# Split string into fields in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON:

```
{"item":2, "url":"domain/house/23/bedroom"}
```

I'm trying to use jq to obtain this new JSON:

```
{"item":2, "number":"23", "room":"bedroom"}
```

Is it possible to do this in JQ? As a first step, I tried to use the capture function to catch the substring after "/house/", but it doesn't work:

```
cat myjson.json | jq -c '{item:.item,substring:(.url | capture("/house/.*").substring)}'
```

Is there a way to extract both values and put them in two different fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split `url` by slashes, and use the result for generating new fields.

```
{item} + (.url / "/" | {number: .[-2], room: .[-1]})
```